# Listen for Mail Change Notification Using Microsoft Graph API in C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I've created an asp.net core application for outlook changenotification in Microsoft graph

please refer this link for the code https://github.com/Su-s/OutlookGraphWebhook

on starting application the below issue is occurring.

### use-case: where the sample scenario will use.

the application has a list of users not related to the Microsoft account. the users are created and managed locally with the help of a db. once the user logged into the application
the user will be accessible to subscribe API. user can login into some Microsoft account and should be able to create a subscription. one user in application is also able to use multiple Microsoft account to create mail subscriptions.

---

please help me to resolve the issue

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IAuthorizationHeaderProvider Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.DefaultAuthorizationHeaderProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore'.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Lenovo\source\repos\OutlookGraphWebhook\OutlookGraphWebhook\OutlookGraphWebhook\Program.cs:line 17
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IAuthorizationHeaderProvider Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.Identity.Web.DefaultAuthorizationHeaderProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.IMsalTokenCacheProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)<---
```

```
    System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProviderOption' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddMicrosoftGraph>b__1_0(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method9(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Cookies=CfDJ8IXWPhWCr-pFqBpbqnKnpRVUJxKt8nedsRjXAM_UecO8XMLDeUyV_zzMn2qreOS5Ii-lJMd-8YYbgRCYPK-EX25rP7UUwNYR3ddIegMxl8qLEjkx0T8RjqZalO7anP59StYuUUcueMv17uRIrSdEGTnvXis36uJeVoJntBO4iLb8h6l-vVH4ZZjchoOf9tw8c4O17dktk4X6hR0d_tWN--EcYwRG_wjssPCR_ASYhC6Te6k50rjVMrHy5y9zVWQlcAty_eEjDlCXjK3f4inx9AfMmzLdB9JSzGpRqdPM3RTW1adYH2VGwOXZKRuxjCAUSNDb9yd4kmmFo41CryzhiNzB4hclSJTIxuD9HUT_ncCOu6x3bky7ZMnbv3q5M8zL1ZQRXkkeJp8SRVmHiDdZei1eLn6H5WC9QyriWKdxZAKbIeyN_Of4gCPhcBt7UNtsK5I25e2lzH-CXZPggBgyM895OYFs5UAAGroAUEz2KSZTX9_CSpN9bUwIM13Juauetl3zBLpo1Lg9N4Rwk74pjpUroyLiB1DpVg5om8utaYjEGYv72swwJDPYNTk_NzrprLXjVC-V2JRe4ITjC4Pou9J-hxA12SeRcbdwOGh3LR7HRq9BssdvvpCuNY1-cV1fSwUBTQeHkmo4IQOgzpPn6RNylgfcRjBXb6xoB8xA_AdkHgFvQ4eXD3SuzJaDmuNHEGmyiWvfIPwlK_buX25Va-rTJD6DoSNDp9WDOWcIrjVLhE6i1nBQU67eW7tfAnj6sQ1bjl5bKF9owWr9RbUrKfL_VfdtOSdKbUNFk94fne-XUpXB_BNsYibq-jtG4IU-O1d1xIHCfZFjGxS7kcvTe2rG_BhISqEk2bVTXhgKR28esE_gcDRzaVuBRwpBqHfHe1rigpliGj3qcUtgalvWMptNMnHWV1YgEPLh7BN_vYaHG45QsVVNbFN8TWBPvz5v1Of1LxDZDf2FhEF_D7yiDIpN93R3ySIqYt7a_UAp3sppKFGCjFHswLH__KKz5xc0dUNuvree9XQym9UQZn70ai74W6lXDIl0w_b2uAffquRqHFyctM12zDcd6eBNsx2LoSyLoOWtUXzlHzOxYoR5uyPWPxGCig-zB7RVJlHac96gHGJ-VC7Yv1d1LM9fqR6be8SU6sYeMXACr8c4CcWdJYaS0mffrSwmL5BWJzjd45-7U8x0wU3llDpoYjmtspSRFdfzdk4VhC3hjQgmMC807iFm22m0hguVGpY6M8k-iREId2IxKBG6An2fV0xLVMhNY07K2VXoMdoI4b6Ia28iee4GQMvqBRy12r1GqVYfyqSq2UpYcLwMMgRRMcQHXARVbg_tpV-gKbmnT4dQkP53EHJZLZBD9xP-GXENtsdLqPtRwdegXg0M_OILUTKUHcJl8Fe0RejaNPmqzpvL5LTZRXqYe4LqDJwLMbkiyfQE-uKAhim5NeWGjxxAYfXv49lm4YKPnN5sg_IPOcagbdWEIP4jh2INvYWmBORjJ26-j4ggOYXulQfjAuz0x7PQNkSmejcMH8yVOlcBDq6qsprlQN-5Bp-IHZ5y3ZaBZOvluMLuPFQRZGybtNmUm8ahCh1NcJhQMk5UL3he49FBbxhQXyrhk16soyrbNaMDT0BVHdyJ3t3yfzTzEbeVioj2V0KKw5qPy2hhfz1nhI7HmoLOIJP4kUrLUL_j8MFcyANiNCSS91OBtyk2FQ8NAgCbMWzZs4CTKn9JUvrNSNBLcZOAoiopcvOzB_VNeHYvhVMOPgOglpNFL5wDAL1z1dmhRwUJet2BZerJaDoeSCPvtuFiLglizEEeci-oWkNRiyVGclW2NCIroMjAnYOUapRsh8BQ8y_USDvZx0yrJCEZf772WzvuOW9rkrVKF2zhIC6ljyF_FkkB8502G-e2xP6pH2_o0rxnAOIIjQFxysIKmZGshQJATUxwZjgGpxxxbSbMSOPirtBywCkpMzawdNgRXXlDlfgpprAGqh6EQbdFi33Gr6pboBpw1CzXomHSYoa-rLpztsoVvkHDRg7WVRrYrpb3DZCJdO0Rf5MTZIX3jZeQX3BHaAYPxqxe7aDbD2h5dHYZOCYTVPW4nX-Fjl8DAJQ2HgFoR25wimIApFL79XjWHa4_REVSzdlGK6pNmA76klSekSudMAFNC3izw-T3Hfb94Y9w48OeQ2ykbSokklp-5euiKCOlEZFB-C5ypQRE0PDdh-wo9q2iJsq5fJpaeihu1BKLCFdJksyhn1_Q6kXbxKZ9JG4W09L6bYKqnAghOluApzQzBQscLeJAZJbRT_GfafDEan4w-E4DmfdYrq064YUkd9iQQwg0udd__HCKHSJ7
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Referer: http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 45
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```